# get distinct and random queryset in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

Hi Im trying to do a queryset that could replace this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (question.exercise_id) question.exercise_id, question.* 
    FROM 
        exercise, question 
    WHERE exercise.id = question.exercise_id
    OFFSET random()*(SELECT count(*) FROM question) LIMIT 5;
```

the before query works fine,

I try to do it in django with

```
random_questions = Questions.objects.filter(
    text=text # text is a Text instance
).distinct('text').order_by('?')[:5]
```

but doesn't work, I search and found that how Im making it never will work but I dont found one alternative solution to that

thanks

Comment: Is that distint? or typo while providing the question? if yes change it to distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt found one answer so the only one way I could found to do it was this:

```
texts = Text.objects.all().order_by('?') # add .prefetch_related('questions_text') or .select_related('questions_text') could help to do the query faster
questions = []
for text in texts:
    questions.append(
        Question.objects.filter(
            text=text
        ).order_by('?')[0]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
random_questions = Questions.objects.filter(
    text=text # text is a Text instance
).distinct('text').order_by('text', '?')
```

And then randomly pick five items from that queryset using len(random_questions) to see how many results there are.  Will be faster than what your are currently doing.

You can also do it with raw sql (but validate your user inputs, if there are any):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly